# How do I change the background color of an animated gif?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to change the background color of an animated gif from blue to red

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit multiple layers at once in animated gif](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65850/edit-multiple-layers-at-once-in-animated-gif)

Answer (score -1):

Normally gif images has n numbers layers, which will open the gif image in photoshop you can see displayed of all layers. Select the background which can change the color according to your interest.